# Finding poles by inspection - R to ground

Tags: frequency

[image]

What does the author mean by total resistance seen at the node to ground? There is no ground connection directly to the resistors.

Comment: Rs is directly connected to ground via Vin. R1 is directly connected to one or the other (or both) of its power supply rails via its output stage, etc. The opamps are ideal voltage (not current) amplifiers, as stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To determine the time constants of a circuit, you must reduce the excitation or the stimulus to zero: you turn the source off. Here, the stimulus is \$V_\text{in}\$ and when made 0 V, it can be replaced by a wire in the circuit. Then, temporarily remove each capacitor and "look" through their terminals to determine the resistance \$R\$ that drives the considered capacitor. Once you have this resistance, the time constant is simply \$\tau=RC\$:

[image]

It is easy here as all \$RC\$ networks are decoupled from each other by the amplifiers. The pole of a 1st-order circuit is the inverse of the time constant. There you go, you have the poles given in the example. To become familiar with this technique, you can have a look at the [seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf) I taught during APEC 2016.

Comment: Very good explanation. What is the reason for 'zeroing' the independent sources here? Is it the same principle that we use to find input and output impedances i.e We zero all independent sources to avoid any current consumption and apply a test voltage source and measure the current

Comment: Just wondering what the theory/proof is behind this 'trick'

Comment: If you want more details, you will have to start looking at the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs. My APEC seminar can get you started but also my [book](https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Circuit-Transfer-Functions-Introduction/dp/1119236371/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8) on the subject. This [paper](https://chic.caltech.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Final-Paper.pdf) is also a good read.

Comment: Thank you. I will check out those!

Answer (score 2):

The author is referring to the Thevenin resistance \$R_\text{Th}\$ seen by each capacitor connected to a particular node. To find \$R_\text{Th}\$, set all sources  to zero. Each amplifier’s output is a voltage source. When they are set to zero, the resistors will be connected to ground.

Comment: In some other books, I have seen the authors say that it is the 'resistance connected to AC ground'

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: @alayoiskgfbfqhxjiw: The system is dc coupled so ac ground is incorrect. The poles affect all signals down to dc.

Answer (score 1):

The impedance looking into node N (for instance) **does not in one bit** depend on the voltage produced by amplifier A1's output so, for convenience, we can set the output of A1 to be 0 volts.

Additionally, we can say that A1's output impedance is zero ohms (unless otherwise specified) therefore, the impedance looking into node N is a resistor (R<sub>1</sub>) in parallel with a capacitor (C<sub>N</sub>).

And, of course we assume A2's input to be infinite (unless otherwise specified).

> *What does the author mean by total resistance seen at the node to
> ground?*

Hence the total resistance at node N to ground is R<sub>1</sub>