# Finding poles by inspection - 2 resistors

Tags: operational-amplifier, frequency-response

[image]

This is a follow on question from

[Finding poles by inspection - R to ground](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/636527/finding-poles-by-inspection-r-to-ground/636536?noredirect=1#comment1685908_636536)

Is this correct? I have tried to follow the approach there.

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: @G36 How can I verify this by simulation without including the op-amp ? I put a 1V ac source at Vin and ran an AC sweep but If I connect a GND to the right side, output will always be 0. If I leave it unconnected , R2 is floating and has no effect. I can never see the effect of R2 for some reason without including the op amp

Comment: Using a traditional method of finding the pole by looking into R2 and putting everything in Laplace domain, it would reveal that R2 has no impact.

Comment: Ground the RHS of R2 and look at the current in R2. With the scale factor of 1/R2 that's obviously just the capacitor voltage.

Comment: R2 affects the pole because of the virtual ground. IOW the op-amp output affects the pole by imposing the virtual ground. If the frequency is high enough that the op-amp no longer behaves as ideal then you'll see some deviation from that. If you connect the op-amp as a voltage follower and R2 to the non-inverting input you'll have the case where R2 has no effect.

Comment: Oui, it is correct but to nitpick, the right side of \$R_2\$ is not shorted to ground but at 0 V. It is important to not confuse a virtual ground with a short circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is this correct?*

Yes, that is correct; R2 feeds a virtual ground hence it acts like a resistor to 0 volts. Then, if you Thevenise R1 and R2 to find the effective resistance of the source (Vin) you find that they are in parallel. Thus, your formula is correct.

[Thevenin tutorial](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/thevenin.html) from HyperPhysics: -

[image]

In the above circuit